# C++11 indexing vector of smart pointers as member of a class

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I have the following classes in my project: `Neuron`, `ActivationNeuron`, `Layer`, and `ActivationLayer` as partly mentioned below.

```
class Neuron { }; /* abstract class */
class ActivationNeuron : public Neuron { };

class Layer {
protected:
    vector<shared_ptr<Neuron>> neurons;
public:
    Neuron& operator[](const int index) {
        return *this->neurons[index];
    }
};

class ActivationLayer : public Layer {
public:
    ActivationNeuron& operator[](const int index) {
        return *static_pointer_cast<ActivationNeuron>(this->neurons[index]);
    }
};
```

I have the following two questions:

- **Implementation/Syntax Related**: Layer now uses `shared_ptr`s of Neurons. How should my implementation change if I plan to use `unique_ptr`s instead, given that `static_pointer_cast` is not available for `unique_ptr` ?
- **Semantics Related:** Should I use `unique_ptr`s at all in this case, given that code in other classes (including my test cases) often invoke the indexing operator to call functions on the `ActivationNeuron` reference ?
- **More Semantics:** The data is guaranteed to be used only as long as a `Layer` instance is in scope (no deferred logging). How is the decision of pointer type affected if I instead choose to return `pointer<Neuron>` and `pointer<ActivationNeuron>` instead of the references? I am more concerned about move/copy semantics and ownership policies rather than (non-drastic) effects in performance.

I also welcome improvements to my current implementation.

Comment: Use [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) to get the actual pointer, and then a normal `static_cast`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/static_pointer_cast/ what you have is equivalent to

```
return *static_cast<ActivationNeuron*>(this->neurons[index].get());
```

The statement above will work for unique_ptr as well.

On the semantics side, you are changing the ownership model. Before anybody could hold on to the pointers. Now they will be bound to `Layer`. If all usage is while `Layer` exists it should be fine. If you need some components to access the data after `Layer` is destroyed (like deferred logging) then you will run into problems.

Not knowing the larger application is hard to say if there's any issue.

Performance wise: the static cast, indexing and the .get() are almost trivial (O(1) complexity, just memory indexing) and I wouldn't worry too much about their performance. You can do a profile to make sure that this is the case in your application.  You are definitely only marginally worse as compared to `vector<Neuron*>`.

Comment: You are correct!! And no, the data will only be accessed as long as the `Layer` instance is present.

Just one more question (update your current answer with this - I will edit the question):

How does the decision of pointer type change if I instead choose to return `pointer<Neuron>` and `pointer<ActivationNeuron>` instead of the references?

Comment: The main difference is that you can return `nullptr`. Anything you did with the reference is also possible with the pointer. Stylewise returning references is a strong signal that the return value belongs to the object called.

Comment: What if I return a `unique_ptr<ActivationNeuron>` to a caller in my code? Will the slot in the `vector` be invalidated (given that `unique_ptr`s cannot be copied) ?

Comment: No. It will be a compile error. But you're right, it will be because `unique_ptr` cannot be copied. You can do .get() to get a regular pointer but keep ownership in the vector.